# C++ Forward declaration and 'Incomplete type is not allowed' error

Tags: c++, c++-cli, declaration, forward, incomplete-type

I have two classes (or better yet, header files) that are part of my C++ program and I simply can't make this all work! They basically need each other's data in order to function properly, as part of my app.

Don't torture yourself by reading the meat of this code; I just need the *forward declaration* and *mutual inclusion* problem resolved, so only take a look at those parts of the code which matter for this problem.

The error occurs in the second code snippet, at the very end (I had to chop off a huge chunk of code from the first snippet, so I could post the question, I guess it's irrelevant to my problem).

**introForm.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "creditsForm.h"
#include "registerForm.h"
#include "aboutForm.h"
#include "QuizForm.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <time.h>
#ifndef __introForm__H__
#define __introForm__H__

namespace InteractiveQuiz {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    ref class QuizForm;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for introForm
    /// </summary>
    public ref class introForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        introForm(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~introForm()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }

        // Extracts a word from a sentence with a given ordinal number
        string extractWord(int ordinal, string sentence)
        {
            int counter = 0;
            string word;

            for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++)
            {
                if (sentence[i] == ',')
                {
                    if (sentence [i+1] != ',')
                    {
                        counter ++;

                        if (counter == ordinal)
                        {
                            return word;
                        }

                        word ="";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    word += sentence[i];
                }       
            }
        }

private: System::Void btnExit1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             exit(1);
         }
private: System::Void btnCredits1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             creditsForm^ credits = gcnew creditsForm;
             credits->Show();
         }
private: System::Void registerBtn_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             registerForm^ registerUser = gcnew registerForm;
             registerUser->Show();
         }
private: System::Void aboutToolStripMenuItem_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             aboutForm^ aboutApp = gcnew aboutForm;
             aboutApp->Show();
         }
private: System::Void quitToolStripMenuItem_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             introForm::Close();
         }
private: System::Void introForm_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             ifstream regUsers ("regUsers.csv");

             if (regUsers)
             {
                 lblUser->Enabled = true;
                 lblPass->Enabled = true;

                 logUsername->Enabled = true;
                 logPassword->Enabled = true;

                 btnLogSubmit->Enabled = true;
                 if (lblLogin->Text == L"Not logged in")
                 {
                    quizLogo->Visible = false;
                 }
             }
             else
             {
                 lblUser->Enabled = false;
                 lblPass->Enabled = false;

                 logUsername->Enabled = false;
                 logPassword->Enabled = false;

                 btnLogSubmit->Enabled = false;

                 quizLogo->Visible = true;
             }

             regUsers.close();
         }

public: String^ loggedUser;

private: System::Void btnLogSubmit_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             if (logUsername->Text->Length < 6 && logPassword->Text->Length < 8)
             {
                 errorLabel->Text = L"Username must be at least 6 and password 8 characters long!";
                 errorLabel->Visible = true;
             }
             else if (logUsername->Text->Length < 6)
             {
                 errorLabel->Text = L"Username must be at least 6 characters long!";
                 errorLabel->Visible = true;
             }
             else if (logUsername->Text->Contains(" "))
             {
                 errorLabel->Text = L"Username must not contain spaces!";
                 errorLabel->Visible = true;
             }
             else if (logPassword->Text->Length < 8)
             {
                 errorLabel->Text = L"Password must be at least 8 characters long!";
                 errorLabel->Visible = true;
             }
             if (logUsername->Text->Length >= 6 && logPassword->Text->Length >= 8)
             {
                 String^ result = logUsername->Text + "," + logPassword->Text;
                 string result2 = marshal_as<string>(result);

                 ifstream regUsers("regUsers.csv");
                 string line;
                 string fileUserPass;

                 /* While there is still a line. */
                 while(getline(regUsers, line))
                 {
                     fileUserPass = extractWord(1, line) + "," + extractWord(2,line);

                     if (fileUserPass == result2) // Successful login
                     {
                         lblLogin->Text = L"Logged in as " + logUsername->Text;

                         quizLogo->Visible = true;
                         errorLabel->Visible = false;

                         btnLogout->Enabled = true;

                         startNewToolStripMenuItem->Enabled = true;

                         loggedUser = logUsername->Text;
                     } 
                 }

                 regUsers.close();

                 if (fileUserPass != result2)
                 {
                     errorLabel->Text = L"Username or password incorrect!";
                     errorLabel->Visible = true;
                 }
             }
         }
private: System::Void btnLogout_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             btnLogout->Enabled = false;

             lblLogin->Text = L"Not logged in";

             quizLogo->Visible = false;

             errorLabel->Visible = false;

             logUsername->Clear();
             logPassword->Clear();

             logUsername->Focus();

             startNewToolStripMenuItem->Enabled = false;
         }
private: System::Void startNewToolStripMenuItem_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             QuizForm^ quiz = gcnew QuizForm;
             quiz->Show();
         }
};
}

#endif // !__introForm__H__
```

**QuizForm.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

#ifndef __QuizForm__H__
#define __QuizForm__H__

namespace InteractiveQuiz {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    ref class introForm;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for QuizForm
    /// </summary>
    public ref class QuizForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        QuizForm(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
        }


    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~QuizForm()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TabControl^  tabControl;
    protected: 

    protected: 
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TabPage^  tabPage1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TabPage^  tabPage2;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::MenuStrip^  menuStrip1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripMenuItem^  quizToolStripMenuItem;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripMenuItem^  startNewToolStripMenuItem;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripMenuItem^  endQuizToolStripMenuItem;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripSeparator^  toolStripSeparator1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripMenuItem^  quitToolStripMenuItem;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripMenuItem^  helpToolStripMenuItem;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripMenuItem^  aboutToolStripMenuItem;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  lblQuizLogin;


    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->tabControl = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TabControl());
            this->tabPage1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TabPage());
            this->tabPage2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TabPage());
            this->menuStrip1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::MenuStrip());
            this->quizToolStripMenuItem = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripMenuItem());
            this->startNewToolStripMenuItem = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripMenuItem());
            this->endQuizToolStripMenuItem = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripMenuItem());
            this->toolStripSeparator1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripSeparator());
            this->quitToolStripMenuItem = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripMenuItem());
            this->helpToolStripMenuItem = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripMenuItem());
            this->aboutToolStripMenuItem = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripMenuItem());
            this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->lblQuizLogin = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->tabControl->SuspendLayout();
            this->menuStrip1->SuspendLayout();
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // tabControl
            // 
            this->tabControl->Controls->Add(this->tabPage1);
            this->tabControl->Controls->Add(this->tabPage2);
            this->tabControl->Location = System::Drawing::Point(12, 27);
            this->tabControl->Name = L"tabControl";
            this->tabControl->SelectedIndex = 0;
            this->tabControl->Size = System::Drawing::Size(686, 430);
            this->tabControl->TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // tabPage1
            // 
            this->tabPage1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(4, 22);
            this->tabPage1->Name = L"tabPage1";
            this->tabPage1->Padding = System::Windows::Forms::Padding(3);
            this->tabPage1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(678, 404);
            this->tabPage1->TabIndex = 0;
            this->tabPage1->Text = L"tabPage1";
            this->tabPage1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // tabPage2
            // 
            this->tabPage2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(4, 22);
            this->tabPage2->Name = L"tabPage2";
            this->tabPage2->Padding = System::Windows::Forms::Padding(3);
            this->tabPage2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(678, 404);
            this->tabPage2->TabIndex = 1;
            this->tabPage2->Text = L"tabPage2";
            this->tabPage2->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // menuStrip1
            // 
            this->menuStrip1->Items->AddRange(gcnew cli::array< System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripItem^  >(2) {this->quizToolStripMenuItem, 
                this->helpToolStripMenuItem});
            this->menuStrip1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(0, 0);
            this->menuStrip1->Name = L"menuStrip1";
            this->menuStrip1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(710, 24);
            this->menuStrip1->TabIndex = 1;
            this->menuStrip1->Text = L"menuStrip1";
            // 
            // quizToolStripMenuItem
            // 
            this->quizToolStripMenuItem->DropDownItems->AddRange(gcnew cli::array< System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripItem^  >(4) {this->startNewToolStripMenuItem, 
                this->endQuizToolStripMenuItem, this->toolStripSeparator1, this->quitToolStripMenuItem});
            this->quizToolStripMenuItem->Name = L"quizToolStripMenuItem";
            this->quizToolStripMenuItem->Size = System::Drawing::Size(43, 20);
            this->quizToolStripMenuItem->Text = L"&Quiz";
            // 
            // startNewToolStripMenuItem
            // 
            this->startNewToolStripMenuItem->Name = L"startNewToolStripMenuItem";
            this->startNewToolStripMenuItem->Size = System::Drawing::Size(125, 22);
            this->startNewToolStripMenuItem->Text = L"Start &New";
            // 
            // endQuizToolStripMenuItem
            // 
            this->endQuizToolStripMenuItem->Name = L"endQuizToolStripMenuItem";
            this->endQuizToolStripMenuItem->Size = System::Drawing::Size(125, 22);
            this->endQuizToolStripMenuItem->Text = L"&End Quiz";
            // 
            // toolStripSeparator1
            // 
            this->toolStripSeparator1->Name = L"toolStripSeparator1";
            this->toolStripSeparator1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(122, 6);
            // 
            // quitToolStripMenuItem
            // 
            this->quitToolStripMenuItem->Name = L"quitToolStripMenuItem";
            this->quitToolStripMenuItem->Size = System::Drawing::Size(125, 22);
            this->quitToolStripMenuItem->Text = L"Q&uit";
            // 
            // helpToolStripMenuItem
            // 
            this->helpToolStripMenuItem->DropDownItems->AddRange(gcnew cli::array< System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripItem^  >(1) {this->aboutToolStripMenuItem});
            this->helpToolStripMenuItem->Name = L"helpToolStripMenuItem";
            this->helpToolStripMenuItem->Size = System::Drawing::Size(44, 20);
            this->helpToolStripMenuItem->Text = L"&Help";
            // 
            // aboutToolStripMenuItem
            // 
            this->aboutToolStripMenuItem->Name = L"aboutToolStripMenuItem";
            this->aboutToolStripMenuItem->Size = System::Drawing::Size(116, 22);
            this->aboutToolStripMenuItem->Text = L"&About...";
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(623, 476);
            this->button1->Name = L"button1";
            this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
            this->button1->TabIndex = 2;
            this->button1->Text = L"Close";
            this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // lblQuizLogin
            // 
            this->lblQuizLogin->AutoSize = true;
            this->lblQuizLogin->Location = System::Drawing::Point(12, 489);
            this->lblQuizLogin->Name = L"lblQuizLogin";
            this->lblQuizLogin->Size = System::Drawing::Size(70, 13);
            this->lblQuizLogin->TabIndex = 3;
            this->lblQuizLogin->Text = L"Not logged in";
            // 
            // QuizForm
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(710, 511);
            this->Controls->Add(this->lblQuizLogin);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->tabControl);
            this->Controls->Add(this->menuStrip1);
            this->MainMenuStrip = this->menuStrip1;
            this->MaximizeBox = false;
            this->MinimizeBox = false;
            this->Name = L"QuizForm";
            this->StartPosition = System::Windows::Forms::FormStartPosition::CenterScreen;
            this->Text = L"Interactive Quiz";
            this->Load += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &QuizForm::QuizForm_Load);
            this->tabControl->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->menuStrip1->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->menuStrip1->PerformLayout();
            this->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->PerformLayout();

        }
#pragma endregion

private: System::Void QuizForm_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             introForm^ intro = gcnew introForm; // the second introForm in this line is underlined with the mentioned error
         }
    };
}

#endif // !__QuizForm__H__
```

What you see in these 2 pieces of code is something I constructed as puzzle pieces I found throughout the net, haha. :)

*My goal:* to be able to use a variable from *introForm* inside *QuizForm*.

Thanks in advance!
Boris J.

Comment: Take this to heart: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier

Comment: Throw away most of the code and try to reproduce the problem. That's what I'd do before asking for help.

Comment: That's not C++. At least the 10% of the code I looked at isn't.

Comment: Oh, c'mon guys! I really need a dedicated answer... I'd appreciate it. :) But I'll try and do what Peter said. In a separate project.

Comment: @juanchopanza it's probably C++/CLI

Comment: @juanchopanza It looks like whacky C++/CLI to me. Silly Microsoft!

Comment: This IS C++... I'm studying it at my university! @wRAR I posted almost all the code so you could see the context. I was thinking about 'inventing' another way of doing what I want... without even trying anything about forward declaration thing. Any suggestions? Anyone? Could anyone please just tell me what I should do?

Comment: @PeterWood OK, I'll ask for a refund... they obviously know nothing.

Comment: Yeah, but C++ is widely used in game programming... and many of today's popular applications.

Comment: @PeterWood OK, I got it, but I guess it will be easier to switch to _normal_ C++ after understanding CLI. I'll practice this, and then probably switch to C++ you mention.

Comment: Why are you using `#pragma once` _and_ include guards? Why are you using a [reserved name](http://stackoverflow.com/q/228783/981959) for your include guards? Why are you including headers outside your include guards?

Answer (score 34):

When using forward declarations of objects in C++, keep a few things in mind.

- You cannot allocate an incomplete type, as the compiler doesn't know how big it is yet. This is solved by only using pointers to incomplete types.
- You cannot reference the members of an incomplete type before it's definition is seen by the compiler. This is solved by separating your interface and implementation in to header and code files.
- If you are in a situation where you **have** to use an incomplete type, you're probably doing something wrong. Try to avoid circular references wherever possible.

In regards to your comment:

When you have a forward declaration of a class, like `class foo;`, it's called an incomplete type, as the definition doesn't exist yet. You can refer to it indirectly via pointers, like `foo *bar;`, but you can't use it in any operations that require knowledge of its internals, such as dereferencing it, using functions that it contains, etc. You can make a full declaration of a class, though using function prototypes instead of functions. You can then define the functions in another file. This will allow you to completely define a circular dependency without making anything blow up.
For example:

[On codepad with the headers inline-included.](http://codepad.org/UAaW91DG)

The individual files:

foo.h:

```
#ifndef __FOO_H_INCLUDE
    #define __FOO_H_INCLUDE
    #ifndef __FOO_H_DEFINED
        #define __FOO_H_DEFINED
        class foo;
        #include "bar.h"
    #endif
    class foo{
        bar *a;
        int b;
        public:
        foo( int _b );
        bar& getbar();
        int getb();
        void setbar( bar* _a );
    };
#endif
```

bar.h:

```
#ifndef __BAR_H_INCLUDE
    #define __BAR_H_INCLUDE
    #ifndef __BAR_H_DEFINED
        #define __BAR_H_DEFINED
        class bar;
        #include "foo.h"
    #endif
    class bar{
        foo *a;
        int b;
        public:
        bar(int _b );
        foo& getfoo();
        int getb();
        void setfoo( foo* _a );
    };
#endif
```

main.cpp:

```
#include<iostream>
#include "foo.h"
#include "bar.h"

foo::foo( int _b ){ b = _b;}
int foo::getb(){ return b; }
bar& foo::getbar(){ return *a; }
void foo::setbar( bar* _a){ a = _a; }

bar::bar( int _b ){ b = _b;}
int bar::getb(){ return b; }
foo& bar::getfoo(){ return *a; }
void bar::setfoo( foo* _a ){ a = _a; }



int main(){
    foo a(5);
    bar b(20);
    a.setbar(&b);
    b.setfoo(&a);
    std::cout   << a.getbar().getfoo().getbar().getb() 
                << "\n" 
                << a.getbar().getfoo().getbar().getfoo().getb();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't quite get what you said; I'm not so 'deep' into that terminology yet. Could you please tell me where I'm wrong and how can I achieve what I need? I need to access a variable from the introForm.h from inside the QuizForm.h, but I can't because introForm.h includes QuizForm.h, so I can't simply include introForm.h in QuizForm.h. 'cause that would be mutual inclusion. Suggestions?

Comment: I updated the answer with a code example that solves your problem in the most sane way.

Comment: Thanks... I'll take your sample into consideration!